# Listview Control with datapager: How to export to excel and get all data

Tags: c#, excel, listview, sqldatasource, datapager

I am having an issue with getting all of the data to export from a Listview control with datapager to excel.  This is my code:

```
    private void ExportListView()
    {

        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=sample.xls");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringWriter objStringWriter = new StringWriter(sb);
        HtmlTextWriter objHtmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(objStringWriter);

        //gvSample is Gridview server control
        HtmlForm frm = new HtmlForm();
        ListView1.Parent.Controls.Add(frm);
        frm.Attributes["runat"] = "server";
        frm.Controls.Add(ListView1);

        DataPager pager = (DataPager)ListView1.FindControl("DataPager1");
        pager.PageSize = 1000000;
        frm.RenderControl(objHtmlTextWriter);

        Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
        Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble());
        Response.Write(objStringWriter);
        Response.End();


        //string attachment = "attachment; filename=Data.xls";
        //Response.ClearContent();
        //Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
        //Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
        //StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        //HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);



        //// Create a form to contain the grid


        //HtmlForm frm = new HtmlForm();
        //ListView1.Parent.Controls.Add(frm);
        //frm.Attributes["runat"] = "server";
        //frm.Controls.Add(ListView1);


        //frm.RenderControl(htw);
        //Response.Write(sw.ToString());
        //Response.End();
    }
```

Anyone with information on how to do would be great.  The pagination is what is making this impossible.  I need to somehow tell the datapager to disable or max out with all data.  I am just stuck.  There are a million examples out there for Gridview but nothing for ListView and I am wondering if anyone has the answer to this.  Please HELP!!  Thanks!!

Comment: What's the issue? Is it that all of the data is not exporting?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  The only data that is coming over is the first page of the ListView.